# Where can I find documentation on Ember's {{control}}?

Tags: ember.js

I don't see a listing in the Ember API. Where can I find which parameters for this template method? Can I use it, given that it's an unfinished feature?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use `{{control}}` yet as it is still being developed and is very likely to change behaviour. Basically it will be like a sandboxed `{{render}}` which won't inherit any context. It is mentioned on [this page](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/) of the emberjs guide:

> {{control}} works like render, except it uses a new controller instance for every call, instead of reusing the singleton controller.
>
> This helper is currently under heavy development, and will likely change soon.